# How to run python script in Rstudio

Tags: python, r, rpython

I have a problem on how to run a python script from Rstudio?

My initial idea is to grab the python script from a GitHub repository then run it in R, I grabbed python code by using `script <- getURL(URL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)`, from *RCurl* package, I was stuck on how to run Python code without storing the script as a file in the working directory, that is, running the R variable **script** above directory in Rstudio.

I did know `python.load()` in `_rPython_` package in R could help to run Python script, but it requires the .py file as the first argument. I would like to find a way without storing the Python script as a file.

Thank you in advance if you have any idea of this problem.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the url from which you're getting the `script` object? What does the object `script` look like?

Comment: Look into the `reticulate` package: https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/26/reticulate-r-interface-to-python/

Comment: if you download the script, then you can just say `system("python path/to/script.py")`

Comment: @FredBoehm, the URL could be found any python codes from Github repository by cilck **Raw** button to generate .e.g. [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/typing/master/python2/test_typing.py), and `script` from `script <- getURL(URL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)` is a character vector, it's all the content (codes) in that URL.

Comment: @lefft thanks and I knew, but I would like to find a way without downloading script.

Comment: ya makes sense, you can always just dl it to a temp file that disappears with the session tho :)

Comment: I am adding support for sourcing a URL in reticulate ([Github pull request here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/pull/213)). Once it's merged, you should be able to source it directly using `reticulate::source_python()`.

Comment: @Tianxxx It's merged now. If you do a `devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`, you can then `reticulate::source_python(URL)` to source your script directly.

Comment: @YuanTang, thanks a lot, I will have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're running an R Markdown file and have `reticulate` installed.

Load and configure your Python version:

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(reticulate)
use_python("usr/local/bin/python")
```
````

Then, any `python` code can be called as follows:

````
```{python}
# write python
# code here
```
````

If you create any global python objects and want to use them with `R` code, simply preface them with `py$`; e.g. to access a dataframe created with python called `my_data` in an R chunk:

````
```{r}
head(py$my_data)
```
````

More details can be found [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html).

Comment: Great start. Is there a way to call a script with arguments and just get the stdout of the python script? e.g., `py_output <- %run ./mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2 ... `?

Comment: I just ran across [this](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate): "Sourcing Python scripts — The `source_python()` function enables you to source a Python script the same way you would `source()` an R script (Python functions and objects defined within the script become directly available to the R session).